# Issue with Sharepoint 2010 application page

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am fairly new to both c# and sharepoint and have a very basic piece of code that is behaving unexpectedly. I am clearly lacking some of the basic troubleshooting skills here and was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

I have an application page with one button and one label. I have a bit of code in the page load event to retrieve some information from an external list which works just fine. I have an exact copy of the code in the button which returns an error. I'd like to know why the button is returning an error when the same code in the pageload event seems fine and dandy.

The C# code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Text;

namespace farmBDCProj2.Layouts.farmBDCProj2
{
    public partial class TestGetInfo : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append("<h2>Generated by PageLoad event</h2>");
            SPContext context = SPContext.Current;
            using(SPSite site = context.Site)
            using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs["BDC_SQL"])
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["BDC_SQL"];
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    output.AppendFormat("<br>item: {0}", item["ADName"]);
                }
            }
            Label1.Text = output.ToString();
        }

        public void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append("<h2>Generated by button click event</h2>");
            SPContext context = SPContext.Current;
            using (SPSite site = context.Site)
            using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs["BDC_SQL"])
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["BDC_SQL"];
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    output.AppendFormat("<br>item: {0}", item["ADName"]);
                }
            }
            Label1.Text = output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The ASPX page:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestGetInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="farmBDCProj2.Layouts.farmBDCProj2.TestGetInfo" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="btn_click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
Application Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
My Application Page
</asp:Content>
```

The error I get is at the 'foreach' stage of the btn_click event and the error text is as follows:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Access denied by Business Data Connectivity.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint
  ErrorCode=-2146232832
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetEntityInstanceEnumerator(XmlNode xnMethodAndFilters)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFilteredEntityInstancesInternal(XmlDocument xdQueryView, Boolean fFormatDates, Boolean fUTCToLocal, String firstRowId, Boolean fBackwardsPaging, String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageRow, List`1& lstColumnNames, Dictionary`2& dictColumnsUsed, List`1& mapRowOrdering, List`1& lstEntityData)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetFilteredEntityInstances(XmlDocument xdQueryView, Boolean fFormatDates, Boolean fUTCToLocal, String firstRowId, Boolean fBackwardsPaging, String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageRow, List`1& lstColumnNames, Dictionary`2& dictColumnsUsed, List`1& mapRowOrdering, List`1& lstEntityData)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureEntityDataViewAndOrdering(String& bdcidFirstRow, String& bdcidNextPageFirstRow)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEntityInstanceEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at farmBDCProj2.Layouts.farmBDCProj2.TestGetInfo.btn_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure.AccessDeniedException
       Message=Access denied by Business Data Connectivity.
       Source=Microsoft.SharePoint
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.DataClassRuntime.ExecuteInternal(IDataClass thisDataClass, ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance, ILobSystem lobSystem, IMethodInstance methodInstanceToExecute, IMethod methodToExecute, IParameterCollection nonReturnParameters, Object[]& overrideArgs)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.EntityRuntime.ExecuteInternal(IDataClass thisDataClass, ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance, ILobSystem lobSystem, IMethodInstance methodInstanceToExecute, IMethod methodToExecute, IParameterCollection nonReturnParameters, Object[]& overrideArgs, IFilterCollection filters)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.EntityRuntime.ExecuteFiltered(IEntity this, IFilterCollection filterCollection, IMethodInstance methodInstanceToExecute, ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.EntityRuntime.<FindFiltered>b__3(IEntity e, IMethodInstance mi, IFilterCollection fc, ILobSystemInstance lsi)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Runtime.EntityInstanceEnumeratorFactory.CreateEntityInstanceEnumerator(IEntity entity, IMethodInstance methodInstance, IFilterCollection filters, ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance, ExecutionCallBack executionCallBack)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Static.Entity.FindFiltered(IFilterCollection filterCollection, String finderName, ILobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance)
            at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.GetEntityInstanceEnumerator(XmlNode xnMethodAndFilters)
       InnerException:
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: This may have nothing to do with it, but if you're dealing with the current site and web then you should be disposing those objects. Only dispose when those objects aren't in the current scope. This can cause odd issues. The using construct calls the dispose method automatically. It's a sharepoint oddity.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by ScottE you've disposed the Web and Site instances, which are provided by SPContext. That's wrong. You may not dispose them.

On the other site you're executing the code way to often. Have a look at the ASP.NET Lifecycle. In the case of a postback (button click) your logic is executed within the Load Method (Page_Load_Stage) and the click handler (Event_stage). In addition to these two things you've to ensure that the user, which is browsing to this ApplicationPage have at least read permissions on this external contenttype.

The exception says, that the current users has no rights to read the requested external contenttype which is associated with the BDC_SQL list.

Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

A belated contribution, but still may be of some use to others:
http://troyscott.ca/2010/07/09/setting-permissions-for-an-external-content-type/